# How can I disable double pressing Esc closes the active window on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11, and whenever I hit my <kbd>Esc</kbd> key twice, it closes the active window.

I would like to disable this feature, and have not been able to track down how to do so.

What's causing this? Is this default behaviour in Windows?

I've tried the following, but the behaviour persists, and I'm not sure where it's coming from

- removing power toys
- using different keyboards
- not using [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) for anything

Comment: Not happening here on either of my Windows 11 Pro machines.  I will keep looking around but I do not see anything common causing this issue.

Comment: I have Power Toys and just updated it. Power Toys does not cause this issue either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably [CClose](https://chaohershi.github.io/cclose/) according to [this user comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/polfeu/comment/hn8typy/) on a reddit **r/pcmasterrace** thread ["Pressing Esc key twice in windows 10 closes the active windows!"](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/polfeu/pressing_esc_key_twice_in_windows_10_closes_the/)

Comment: I've tried finding it on my system, but it doesn't appear to be there. I tried `tasklist | findstr close`, but no results. I've never intentionally installed it, and though not super familiar with Windows, am a mac developer who is good on terminal/knows when he's usually installing things :D. It's not there when I go to `Add/Remove programs` either

Comment: @BradParks findstr is case sensitive.  The executable name is CClose.exe.  I tried to install it just out of curiosity.  `tasklist | findstr | Close` finds the process.  Once I exit, the process no longer shows up and the double Esc behavior is gone.  But if you don't have it, I don't know where else to suggest.  If I do, I'll update this answer and message you.

Comment: hmm.... tried that too, but still nothing shows up - ie no CClose

Comment: @BradParks Sorry it didn't work.  The search continues....  Maybe inspect each line of the tasklist output?  Do a WinMerge comparison with another Windows 11 PC?

Comment: Thanks - I will post back if I find my particular issue, but believe your answer is probably it for most users!

Comment: Found it - posted as an answer: https://superuser.com/a/1751128/38941  Thanks for the help! Since your answer is the more common cause, I expect, I've selected it as the answer :D

Comment: @BradParks Thanks.  I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Found it, lol! It was an app I installed to try and customize my keyboard to be more Mac like to me, called "FastKeys". Seems to work great, but the option to close windows on double tapping "Esc" was in the "Shortcuts" section!